# YouTube Content ID API suddenly giving 403 for everything

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I've been working with the Content ID API, built a couple of scripts that were working fine, but now all requests are giving me a 403. I've tried even the simplest use case: fetching info for a single asset from Google's own [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/assets/get#try-it). So it's nothing to do with how I'm managing authentication on my end or anything.

Everything on the API console appears to be in order: I've to an API client properly configured and accessible by the account I'm using. Usage is well below quota.

The error response that is returned is not at all helpful:

```
403 Forbidden

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  118
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sun, 25 Aug 2013 19:56:17 GMT
expires:  Sun, 25 Aug 2013 19:56:17 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have Off the Content ID API on your API Console. This is, by the general, the error message returned for this problem.

Comment: The console settings were all good. It just started working again without me changing anything, so I don't know what the issue was. Probably something temporary on their end.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs of Youtube Content ID API, the 403 results due to below reason.

If the API returns an HTTP 403 response code, then your application may not be registered. Many APIs set a query-volume limit of 0 for unregistered applications and return a 403 response code when the query-volume limit is exceeded.